# Any free mapping service to display and filter 250000+ datapoints?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, d3.js, visualization, google-fusion-tables

I have participated in a Hackathon in my city, and the traffic department made public a dataset with more than 250 thousand traffic accident datapoints, each one containing Latitude, Longitude, type of accident, vehicles involved, etc.

I made a test to display the data using Google Maps API and Google Fusion Tables, but the usage limits were quickly reached with the first two years of a total of 13 years of records.

The data for two years can be [displayed and filtered here](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1ZELJGR3oOINab5YxcRSERlTT_SgKnRWi2hu6zno).

So my question is:

> Which free online services could I use in order to interactively display and filter 250 thousand such datapoints as map layers?

It is important that the service be free, because we are volunteering our time for non-profit public good. Currently our City Hall is implementing an API, but it is not ready yet, and it would be useful to present them some popularly well-accepted use-cases to make some political pressure for further API development with THEIR server (specially remotely querying a database instead of crawling a bunch of .csv files as it is now...)

An alternative would be to put everything in GitHub and load the whole dataset client-side to be manipulated with D3.js for example, but that seems very inefficient either for the client/user as for the server.

Thanks for reading, and feel free to re-tag if needed.

Comment: You're going to have problems with that amount of unfiltered data points with D3.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff even with local static data in Google Maps the browser becomes VERY slow... Perhaps a desktop GUI program would be more indicated, but I'd like to keep that as a last resort...

Comment: You almost certainly want to prefilter the data in some meaningful way.

Answer (score 2):

You need Google Maps API for Business to achieve what you want, but it costs a lot of money.

However, in some cases, you can get this Business Licence if you work for non-profit organization. I can't find the exact rules to be eligible for this free licence. I tried googled them but I can't find anything. I only find [this link](http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/grants/software/mapsapi.html?hl=en-EN), just take a look if it can answer your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that with Google Fusion Tables. The limit is 100,000 points per table, but you can overlay 5 layers onto a single map so in effect you can reach 500,000 points. I implemented the website below and have run it with over 200,000 points.

http://www.skyscan.co.uk/mapsearch.html

Comment: I'll need some time to put my stuff together, but it's good to know that it's at least theoretically possible. There are some issues regarding queries and filtering, but something is better than nothing. Thanks!